# Error getting access token in keycloak from Angular

Tags: angular, jwt, keycloak

I am working on a project composed of angular (16) on the front and spring boot (3.2) on the backend. To provide them with security I am using keycloak (using a Docker container in version 23.0.4). I have already configured security on the backend and it works perfectly for me. I am doing some initial tests on the front to obtain the access token to keycloak before making the request to Spring Boot.

When making the request to obtain the token using the URL http://localhost:8080/realms/dev-env/protocol/openid-connect/token/, the following message is returned: “Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost: 8080/realms/dev-env/protocol/openid-connect/token/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.”
If I make this same request in Postman it works correctly.

This is the code I'm running in Angular to get the token:

```
obtainToken(): Observable<any>{
     let url = 'http://localhost:8080/realms/dev-env/protocol/openid-connect/token/';
     let formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("client_id", "ekindb-review-api-rest");
     formData.append("grant_type", "password");
     formData.append("username", "ivett");
     formData.append("password", "start");
     formData.append("client_secret", "QGDEARrlpFUZqjLwuOz5H11HsFhXvrp8");
    let head = new HttpHeaders(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      });
    return this.http.post(url, formData, {headers: head});
  }

  obtainHeader(token : string) : HttpHeaders{
    return new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    });
  }

  getDbEntriesToday(): Observable<any> {
    this.obtainToken().subscribe(data1=>{
      console.log(data1)
    }, error => console.error(error));
    return this.obtainToken().pipe((data : any)=>{
      let token : string  = data.access_token;
      console.log(data);
      return this.http.get(this.apiRestDirection + "/pesajesLinea/pesajesToday", {headers : this.obtainHeader(token)});
    });
  }
```

I have tried adding a new web origin in the keycloak client configuration, but it still doesn't work for me. I have not made the guard configurations nor have I added the keycloak dependencies to the angular project. I don't know if this is the cause of the problem.

[image: Client Configuration]

Can you help me, please?